# Why the setPixel is slower in android lollipop than in android KitKat

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I want to transplant the app from android kitkat to lollipop and I find the setPixel becomes slower in lollipop.

The function of app is only drawing the Bitmap from buffer; however, it take about 15 times longer in android lollipop.

How can I improve my code?
Thanks.

```
public Bitmap draw(byte[] buffer) {
    Bitmap pic = Bitmap.createBitmap(200, 200, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    for (int i = 0; i < 150; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 180; j++) {
            byte temp = (byte) (buffer[(i*180 + j)]);
            int color=0xff000000;
            color = color ^ temp << 24; 
            pic.setPixel(i+10, j+10, color);
        }   
    }
    return pic;
}
```

Comment: Consider using RenderScript: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/index.html or parallelize your loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are setting multiple pixels, you should always use [setPixels()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#setPixels(int[],%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) rather than individually calling `setPixel()`.

Comment: I try the setPixels() and it works normally. Thanks :D

Comment: If this helped answer your question, remember to accept the answer to remove your question from the queue of unanswered questions. Best of luck!